# How sorting is happening here and comparison between cap's and small letters?

Tags: java, sorting, collections, scjp

```
public class BioDiesel {
            public static void main(String args[]) {
                LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
                list.add("BbB1");
                list.add("bBb2");
                list.add("bbB3");
                list.add("BBb4");
                Collections.sort(list);
                for (String str : list) {
                    System.out.print(str + ":");
                }
            }
}
```

Code is running fine and displaying the result in a sorted order. Can someone explain how sorting is performed in case of above provided String elements?

How come the output is :

```
BBb4:BbB1:bBb2:bbB3:
```

Comment: Please try and improve your question. Sorry but it’s hard to understand what are you asking. Instead of pasting some code with a short cover note, try providing more exposition: what's the problem you're solving, what's your intended solution, what obstacles you're facing, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that I understood your question correctly, this should work:

```
Collections.sort(list, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```

[`String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER) is a comparator class that disregards the case when comparing strings.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with [the documentation for `Collections.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29):

> Sorts the specified list into ascending order, according to the natural ordering of its elements.

What's the **natural ordering** of a string? [`String` can tell us](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29):

> The comparison is based on the Unicode value of each character in the strings.

And of course, the unicode value of `b` is higher than the unicode value of `B`.

If you want a case-insensitive sort, there's [a form of `sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) that takes a `Comparator`, and `String` helpfully provides a pre-made [`CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER) comparator.